# Aside from Praat, which are the professional options for speech analysis?

Tags: phonetics, praat, forensic-linguistics

I'm working as a forensic linguist at an upcoming trial. No details to share, but I need something highly professional.

Praat is obviously a fine speech analysis program (and I know it well from my university days) -- but is that the program commonly used in industry? What other, more professional options are out there?

Comment: Some phoneticians use Emu, but I don't think it would be regarded as more 'professional' than Praat. Some also use Matlab, which is relatively pricey, and arguably more 'professional' - I don't know whether there are are any real arguments to prefer Matlab. Perhaps its scripting language is more accomodating than Praat's.

Comment: How did you get employed as an expert for a trial?

Answer (score 2):

For your purpose, you might want to investigate [Forensic Audio Workstation](http://speechpro-usa.com/product/forensic_analysis/faw).

Comment: Have you used this program before? How does it compare?

Comment: No, it just seems to be a candidate for being a professional forensic speech analysis tool (which you might be called on to know about even if you don't use it).